# Display pictures from URL into UICollectionView on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

How to display photos on URL into UICollectionView also make paging for photos , any help please

```
NSString *MyPatternString=[self.PatternImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.PattImagCollection.image=[UIImage imageNamed:MyPatternString ];
```

Comment: You will need to give us some more information, like what is in the `MyPatternString`. Also in Objective-C variable and properties should not start with a capital. So `MyPatternString` should be `myPatternString`. The same goes for `PatternImages` and `PattImagCollection`.

Comment: ok @rckoenes this is my code ....................................
   {self.urlAddress = @"http://ns1.vm1692.sgvps.net/~karasi/visitjordan/gallery/";
self.PatternImages=@[@"010.jpg",@"011.jpg"];
}
  
, am using pictures on my computer that I saved on  array "PatternImages ", so now i need another way to bring pictures from an URL"http://ns1.vm1692.sgvps.net/~karasi/visitjordan/gallery/" and displayed on same way on UICollection View...

Comment: and whats i  mean of PattImagCollection it's UIImageView on cells on collection view .

Comment: `imageNamed:` only loads images from the app bundle or assets file. You will need to write code to load the image from the web. Use Google there are plenty of example around for this.

Comment: assets file, yes that's what i need  load images and displayed on uicollectionview.

Comment: You are telling two different things, the assest file is something you create in Xcode, the code you posted contains URL to image on the web. Please make up your mind what you want to do, explain it more in your question **NOT** a comment and try and solve the issue yourself before asking

Comment: @rckoenes does the link work with u, did u see how link contain images as array http://ns1.vm1692.sgvps.net/~karasi/visitjordan/gallery/

Comment: yes i know , my code with assets file its work correctly , i need another way to display photos from url , and sorry for annoy :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData
    dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:YourURL]]];
```

cell.yourimageviewname.image = image;